# Selecting elements by text with CSS3 selectors in CasperJS

Tags: css, css-selectors, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm doing functional testing using CasperJS's [test class](http://casperjs.org/testing.html), and can't seem to select elements by their text values. My goal is to check that a class of div is visible, and then check it has the value I expect.

I've tried using the CSS3 selectors mentioned on [CaspersJS' selector page](http://casperjs.org/selectors.html), but must be doing something wrong. None of the following work for me (all enclosed in `""`):

- `div#myid[text()='sometext']`
- `div#myid[text='sometext']`
- `div#myid[text=sometext]`
- `div#myid:contains('sometext')`
- `div#myid:contains(sometext)`

Any pointers as to how I can select a specific element based on it's text value?

Comment: `:contains()` is not in the spec anymore, and no browsers implement it natively. There is no way to select an element by its text in CSS; you'll have to use XPath instead.

Comment: You could throw some jQuery at this and check for equivalence or similarity of values on `.text()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments above - I ended up going with using jQuery (as it was being loaded on the client) through `evaluate()` calls in the CasperJS tests.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
this.test.assertExists(x('//*[@id="myid"][text()="sometext"]'), 'the element exists');
```

Comment: This is the way to go. No need to inject jQuery into the page just to do some selects. Although in this case it was already loaded.